# Shufle text value from array and display only one

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to extract one value from array (that's easy) but...
I have 5 words: banana, apple, lemon, orange, apricot wich is show on screen.
I need to random chose one value to show on screen and hide another 4.

Ex:
1. banana
2. apple
3. lemon
4. orange
5. apricot

On click (every where) i need to see:
1. nothing
2. nothing
3. lemon (random)
4. nothing
5. nothing

Comment: This question is already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/getting-random-value-from-an-array

Comment: Java or Javascript? Those are not the same at all

Comment: java script for html.

Comment: I know how to extract as random from array but i need to set another 4 values to nothing. Ex: on screen i have 5 div wich display 5 value (banana, apple, lemon, orange and apricot. On click i must see one single random value in div but all the rest must show "nothing"

Comment: wrap them in spans and set their `display:none`

Comment: How you are displaying them on the page is part of the solution. Can you add the HTML you're currently using?

Comment: [code]<table width="100%" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td><div class="value1">banana</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="value2">apple</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="value3">lemon</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="value4">orange</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="value5">apricot</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide all the fruits, then show one selectively. I've made a working example here: http://codepen.io/gunderson/pen/zxWQMV

html

```
<button id="changer">Change Fruit</button>
<div class="container">
    <span class="apple">Apple</span>
    <span class="banana">Banana</span>
    <span class="lemon">Lemon</span>
    <span class="orange">Orange</span>
    <span class="apricot">Apricot</span>
</div>
```

css

```
.container span {
    display: none;
}
```

js w/jquery

```
$("#changer").click(changeFruit);

function changeFruit(){
  var index = (Math.random() * 5) >> 0;

  $(".container span")
    .hide()
    .eq(index).show();
}
```

vanilla js

```
document.querySelector("#changer").addEventListener("click", changeFruit);

function changeFruit(){
  var index = (Math.random() * 5) >> 0;
  var spans = document.querySelectorAll(".container span");
  for (var i = 0, endi=spans.length; i < endi; i++){
    spans[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  spans[index].style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: so far is good and i wish to thank you but i see only one fruit wich is change after i press 'Change fruit' button. i don't wish show only one value. I need to extract one fruit and the rest of 4 fruit to change value to 'nothing' or 'not available'

Comment: I need to have 5 differnt div with text Apple | Banana | Lemon | Orange | Apricot - click on button must hide 4 fruit wich is rename/change name to 'nothing'  Nothing | Banana | Nothing | Nothing | Nothing

Comment: You can use this same technique to accomplish that. Just add a second layer inside each span so you have `span.available` that contains your fruit name, and `span.unavailable` that is your "not available" message and toggle those accordingly.

Comment: This is not a place for people to do your homework for you. http://codepen.io/gunderson/pen/zxWQMV